# Does the output of --export-ssh-key change with different subkeys?

Tags: gnupg, yubikey

I use `gpg --export-ssh-key` to generate a public RSA key I can add to my `authorized_keys` file for the purposes of accessing my server via SSH. I have two Yubikeys (Yubikey 5 NFC) with the same subkeys on each of them. Ideally I want each Yubikey to have their own subkeys instead of sharing one. If I do this, will the same exported SSH key work with multiple subkeys? My concern is, if I lose one Yubikey, can I still log into my server using the backup Yubikey, even though I generated unique subkeys for them with the same master key?